# Automatically Update All Web References in a Project in VS

Tags: visual-studio, web-reference

If I have a project file with 50+ web references, instead of going over each web reference
one by one and doing right-click-->Update, is there a way to have Visual Studio do it automatically?

Comment: This question looks to have the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159599/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-web-reference-at-build-time

Answer (score 7):

With VS you can make multiple selection with ctrl + left mouse click and than you can make update action.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to automate this process. For example, right before building the solution, have VS to discover all existing web references and update them all.

Comment: Please note, this doesn't work across multiple projects.