# Automated Web Reference Switching in C# project with NAnt

Tags: c#-4.0, nant, web-reference

Problem: I have a C# 4.0 project with web references in Visual Studio 2010. I have two sets of web references, but I do not want to use them simultaneously. I want to be able to automatically remove all my current ones, add all the new ones, and then do the equivalent of 'update web reference' on each of them. I'm having a difficult time even finding where to start.

After searching around, I've found NAnt, which looks like it may be able to accomplish what I'm after (with the wsdl command), but I'm in unfamiliar territory.

Question: Is NAnt the right tool for this job? Will I be wasting time if I learn to use it? Is there a simple solution that I'm just not seeing? I'm more just looking for some guidance than a hammered out solution.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested:

After doing more research, I think I'm going to use some combination of 
[MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd%28VS.100%29.aspx),
[How to call MSBuild from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536539/how-to-call-msbuild-from-c-sharp),
and
[How do I automatically update a web reference at build time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159599/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-web-reference-at-build-time)

I'll update this answer with my solution when I'm done.